# JS: window.open - how to set Open Sans font?

Tags: javascript, printing, font-family

I can't get it work. The only thing I need - set all content font family to `'Open Sans'`. Here is what I have right now

```
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width="100%",height="100%"');
        popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link href=\'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans\' rel=\'stylesheet\' type=\'text/css\'></head><body>' + content + '</body></html>');
        popupWin.document.body.setAttribute('style', 'font-family: \'Open Sans\' !important');
        popupWin.document.close();
        popupWin.print();
        popupWin.close();
    }
```

This piece of code show empty page, but when I removing `link` attribute the content is showing, but with default family. Any ideas?

P.S. content variable holds a simple html markup, I was trying to set style like

`<div style="font-family='Open Sans'">`

but no luck.

Comment: Are you opening the page from an HTTPS tab? If so, the browser will block your request to "http://....". Try removing the protocoll  `href=\'//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans\'`

Comment: Yes, I'm using an HTTPs, but how can I remove the protocol, the Open Sans is not a standart font, I have to upload it

Comment: The comment shows you how. Just remove `http:` (keep the slashes) from the start of the `href` attribute.

Comment: This gives me just a blank screen, no content showed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `http` to `https`. You might also want to add a delay before printing. Try the following:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  var content = document.querySelector('textarea').innerHTML;

  var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width="100%",height="100%"');
  // Popup locked by browser
  if (!popupWin) {
    console.log('Popup was blocked');
    return false;
  }
  popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head><body>' + content + '</body></html>');
  popupWin.document.body.setAttribute('style', 'font-family: "Open Sans" !important');
  setTimeout(function() {
    popupWin.document.close();
    popupWin.print();
    popupWin.close();
  }, 2000);
};
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
<textarea>Put this on the popup page</textarea>
<button>Print</button>
```

Comment: That's odd, but the problem disappeared only after adding delay, can you explain why?

Comment: I think the print function isn't waiting for resources to be loaded.

Comment: @styfle: Did you mean this insted? `if (!popupWin) {`